# how to get react js post request data in servlet post() controller

Tags: java

below servlet code is not working and values are coming empty for `JSON`     object and null for request `getparameter()`, how to resolve?

Here is **React js** code:

```
processFormData(data){
    console.log("BODY : data : "+ data);
    console.log("sending data to server....");
    return fetch("ServletReactWeb/register", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: { 
            loadProds: 1,
            test: JSON.stringify(data) // look here!
        }                  
    })
   //.then(res => res.json())
   //.then(resp => this.setState({user:resp}))

    .then(function (res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            alert("Request send Successfully!!!");
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        } else if (res.status == 401) {
            alert("Oops! ");
        }
    }, function (e) {
        alert("Error submitting form!");
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
    //.then(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")));     
};
```

created a servlet post method with code in controller for receive the request parameter values.

Here is **servlet** code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // doGet(req, resp);
    // readContent(req,resp);
    System.out.println("Request Data : "+req.getParameter("test"));
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(req.getReader());
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jb.append(line);
        }           
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonObject =  gson.toJson(jb.toString());
        System.out.println("jsonObject : " + jsonObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // crash and burn
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what is the exact servlet code to solve this problem?